# Is there a way to get emacs's anything to do "fuzzy" searches?

Tags: search, emacs, fuzzy-search

I'm not sure if fuzzy is the correct way to phrase this, so allow me to explain what I want to do.

Often times, I'm looking for files that I know are within a particular directory in my local SVN working copy, and I have an idea what directory they're in, but don't want to think of the precise path or there may be several copies of it in different branches.  For example, suppose I want a file "eligibility.py" that I know is somewhere under a "trunk" directory and in a directory named "interface" below that.

It would be ideal if I could just type in something like this at the anything-for-files prompt:

```
trunk interface eligibility.py
```

Is there any way I can do something similar to this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out.  This functionality is included with [anything-match-plugin.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/anything-match-plugin.el).

Answer (score 6):

I like [`'ifind`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ifind.el) myself.

```
M-x ifind /path/to/trunk/eligibility.py
```

Answer (score 1):

I like using file-cache and ido-find-file: http://sachachua.com/wp/2009/01/06/emacs-file-cache-and-ido/

Comment: It'd be helpful if you described how to integrate that bunch of elisp code with existing anything.el setup.

Answer (score 1):

In **Icicles** you can find files by matching not just the relative file name but any parts of the path.  You can use substring, regexp, and fuzzy matching.  You can AND together multiple search patterns (progressive completion).  See multi-command `icicle-locate-file`.

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_File-Name_Input

You also mentioned fuzzy file-name matching, but that wasn't what your description corresponds to. If you *do* want to also do fuzzy file-name completion of various sorts then see this:

http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Fuzzy_Completion